# IntelliJ class diagram as a "flow" diagram for only 1 class (or alternative)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, class-diagram

I am writing in java SpringBoot and Gradle via IntelliJ.
I want to be able to see all the classes my flow needs and the dependencies between them. The ideal diagram would contain the methods call flow.
But another good enough diagram would give me all the class contained in my flow.
So the best thing is something like:

```
Class1.method1 -> Class2.method2 -> Class3.method3
```

and ok diagram:

```
Class1 -> Class2 -> Class3
```

When trying to use the Diagrams | Show Diagram in a class I have the next options:

[image]

When trying to use `Java Classes` - I am getting a diagram of only the class and its annotations:
[image]

When trying `Gradle Dependencies` / `Spring Beans Dependencies` I am getting it for the whole package, and I am having this super frightening (but very pretty) diagram:
[image]

So it seems like IntelliJ has what I need but it can display it for the whole project, which is not realistic to use it.
Is there a way I can have a diagram for only 1 class (as a root)?
Or alternatively, do you know of another way (e.g. another IDE) to achieve this kind of diagram?

Comment: Could you clarify please? "Java Classes" option shows diagram for selected file or package.

Comment: It shows a diagram for the file class, but instead of the class diagram, it only shows the annotations of the class.

Comment: I want to see the dependencies of the class, you could say a "flow" diagram.

Comment: Please vote the elated request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81834/Show-dependencies-of-a-class-in-UML-diagram-without-manually-opening-the-dependencies

Comment: the fact that this request is 11 years old makes me a bit skeptical about it... But I've upvoted it anyhow :).
So, I understand it is not possible in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, there is no such feature. You may try to build diagram for "src" folder to avoid all dependencies shown.

Comment: Please explain what information do you want to see. IntelliJ can show you methods, fields or properties. Right-Click in the class-diagramm -> Content -> Show Categories -> Fields

Comment: @TobiasOtto I've tried to clarify things, please tell me if my needs are still not clear.

Comment: IntelliJ can show UML [class diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) including fields, methods, inheritance and relations out of the box. What you are probably looking for in order to visualize the 'flow' of methods are [sequence diagrams](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286-sequencediagram).

Comment: @KnightIndustries you are right. This is what I am looking for, but the IntelliJ dependencies diagram should also be suitable for my needs if it just could be applied to 1 class.
I have already checked out the sequence plugin and it is buggy when used on long flows, and has issues displaying flows of classes implementing interfaces or extending abstract classes.
It isn't a good enough solution :(

Comment: So your question is about visualizing all imports of a class? The [dependency analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-analysis.html) can help with this, but for a typical Java class with 20-30 imports, I suspect a diagram would quickly become incomprehensible.